# Add brand logo to company email

Tags: email, google-workspace

I am looking for a good alternative to the expensive BIMI.

My company uses google workspace as an e-mail provider. If I add a logo to a user, if this email is sent to the Google ecosystem, the logo is displayed. This does not appear if I send the email to yahoo, for example.
BiMi allows to show the logo to google, yahoo, aol and others but it is too expensive.
During a test I noticed that stackoverflow does not use BIMI but I see its logo both on gmail and yahoo.

How does?

Which system does it use?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished for free using the following steps:

1. Create a [Google account](https://accounts.google.com/signup) with your company's email address.
2. Change the profile picture to your company's logo.
3. Wait up to 48 hours for the logo to become visible in the inbox.

Do not create the Google account using the "To manage my business" option. This account type isn't able to change its profile picture, and the account type can't be changed after its created.

**For everyone else:** 
First, you will need complete the BIMI specification. Then, you will need to complete any additional requirements that each email service provider may have to display the logo in their inbox. This [tutorial](https://medium.com/p/77d713cb9e45) walks you through the process and explains everything you need to know.

Comment: I am looking for a good alternative to BIMI. For example, StackOverflow emails show the logo but are not registered on BIMI. How is it possible?